# Как определить кодировку html-файла?

Tags: java, html, http

Есть следующая задача: выгрузить html-файл, правильно определив его кодировку. У меня уже имеется объект `URL`, представляющий данный файл. Из этого объекта я получаю `InputStream`, которую могу просто побайтово впихнуть в файл, однако тогда я не определю кодировку. Возникло несколько вопросов:

1) Допустим, я уже определил кодировку. Я так понял что её надо будет использовать при чтении html-файла, точнее когда я создам объект `InputStreamReader(InputStream in, String charsetName)`. Т.е. в параметре `charsetName` как раз надобно указать определённую мной кодировку. Это так?

2) Насколько я знаю, кодировку можно вытащить из самого документа. Один из способов -- разобрать тег `<meta charset="charsetName">`. Если его нет в **выгружаемом** файле (т.е. кодировка в файле на сервере не указана), нужно ли писать этот тег в **записываемый локальный** файл (т.е. указать кодировку, полученную другим способом)?

3) Далее насколько мне известно, кодировка может быть указана в HTTP-ответе сервера, в хедере которого должно присутствовать поле `Content-Type: text/html; charset=charsetName`. Насколько я понял, это лучший способ получить кодировку. Используя объект класса `URL` я могу создать объекты классов `URLConnection` и `HttpURLConnection`. Далее я не знаю как мне вытащить кодировку. У меня есть четыре варианта:

- а) `URLConnection.getContentType()` (видимо, должно вернуть поле
  `Content-Type`)
- б) `URLConnection.getContentEncoding()` (видимо, то что мне нужно, но
  я не уверен)
- в) `HttpURLConnection.responseMessage` (поле защищённое, придётся
  расширить класс и доставать поле `Content-Type`)
- г) `HttpURLConnection.getHeaderField(int n)` (необходимо указать
  номер поля, и тогда метод вернёт `String` этого поля)

Я склоняюсь к варианту б), однако не совсем уверен вернёт ли он мне то что нужно. Кроме того, не очень понятно что будет возвращено если сервер не указал кодировку. Насколько я знаю, есть соглашение об использовании дефолтной кодировки, будет ли она возвращена в таком случае?

Comment: Вы вроде описали все варианты, что мешает взять и попробовать и выбрать тот вариант, который лучше всего подойдет вам?

Comment: Просто на docs.oracle описания методов довольно скупы, а у меня мало опыта чтобы быть 100% уверенным в том, что эти методы не могут вернуть мне то, что мне не нужно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Метод `getContentEncoding()` — это другое. Там пишется, например, что содержимое потока зазиповано. Метод `getContentType()` вам лучше подходит: там как раз будет строка вида `"text/html; charset=charsetName"`. Вообще лучше для общения с HTTP-сервером использовать какую-нибудь библиотеку, например, [Apache HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/index.html). Там есть класс [`ContentType`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/ContentType.html), который может распарсить эту строку. Пользоваться как-то так:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response = client.execute(new HttpGet(url.toURI()));
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
ContentType contentType = ContentType.getOrDefault(entity);
Charset charSet = contentType.getCharset();
InputStream urlStream = entity.getContent(); // отсюда дальше читать как обычно
```